# Why can't we listen to audio using bluetooth head set

Tags: bluetooth, headset, a2dp

While this is perfectly OK while I take calls using my bluetooth headset , why can't we listen to audio using my bluetooth Headset ?

Does the headset software internally built to function only for calls? Can't we make an custom music player which can pair with bluetooth and play the music ?

Answer (score 3):

You can, and I do all the time, however your (unspecified) headset and (unspecified) handset both have to support [A2DP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) (Wikipedia).  Generally earpieces (single ear headsets) don't support A2DP since there's no need (there are a handful of exceptions though).